# How to create 3d region of f[x,y] over triangular region on xy plane?

Tags: plotting, regions

I need to create a VOLUME under `f[x,y]= x (y^3 + 1)^(1/2)` that's above the triangular region bounded by `y=x/3`, `y=2`, and `x=0`.
I know how to make the plot of the function over an area, such as `Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 2}]`. However, I do not know how to make it exclusively over the triangle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] = x (y^3 + 1)^(1/2);

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 6}, {y, x/3, 2}, Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x/3 <= y <= 2 && x >= 0], 
 Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot3D[0 <= z <= f[x, y] && x/3 <= y <= 2 && 0 <= x <= 6,
 {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 18}, PlotPoints -> 51]
```

[image]

```
Maximize[{f[x, y], x >= 0, x/3 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}]
```

> {18, {x -> 6, y -> 2}}

Answer (score 2):

Several methods. one of them is:

```
Plot3D[x (y^3 + 1)^(1/2), {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, y <= 2 && y >= 3 x && x >= 0]]
```

Comment: Great catch. thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! (+1 already.)

Answer (score 2):

In V10+:

```
Plot3D[x (y^3 + 1)^(1/2),
 {x, y} ∈ Polygon[{{0, 0}, {6, 2}, {0, 2}}],
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, Filling -> 0]
```

Also

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[0 <= z <= x (y^3 + 1)^(1/2), {{x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 18}}]
 ]
```

Comment: I tried this and realized I wrote the problem incorrectly. I don't need the slice of f[x,y] over the triangle. Instead I need the volume between the triangle on the xy plane and f[x,y]. It should be a solid with a triangular base. Thank you for your quick response, and I apologize for my poor wording. This is my first time using the program.

Answer (score 1):

`NIntegrate` `x (y^3 + 1)^(1/2)` over `Polygon[{{0, 0}, {6, 2}, {0, 2}}]`:

```
NIntegrate [x (y^3 + 1)^(1/2), {x, y} \[Element] Polygon[{{0, 0}, {6, 2}, {0, 2}}]]
```

Answer:26.